# Is there way to define a variable into my code

Tags: python

```
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
f = lambda x: np.sin(x)
[dyf, Xf] = my_num_diff(f, 0, 2*np.pi, 10, "forward")
[dyb, Xb] = my_num_diff(f, 0, 2*np.pi, 10, "backward")
[dyc, Xc] = my_num_diff(f, 0, 2*np.pi, 10, "central")
plt.figure(figsize = (12, 8))
plt.plot(x, np.cos(x), label = "analytic")
plt.plot(Xf, dyf, label = "forward")
plt.plot(Xb, dyb, label = "backward")
plt.plot(Xc, dyc, label = "central")
plt.legend()
plt.title("Analytic and Numerical Derivatives of Sine")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()
```

this is my code and I get an error: name 'my_num_diff' is not defined

Comment: `my_num_diff` is a function and you haven't  defined it anywhere in your code so you will have to make the function in your code.

Comment: `def my_num_diff(*args): ...`

Answer (score 0):

> *this is my code and I get an error: name 'my_num_diff' is not defined*

Do you have something like:

```
def my_num_diff():
    ...
```

Or like:

```
from mymodule import my_num_diff
```

In your code? The error was probably caused by the fact that the function wasn't declared in that scope.

---

I see you are using your function this way:

```
[dyf, Xf] = my_num_diff(f, 0, 2*np.pi, 10, "forward")
```

So you probably need a function similar to this:

```
def my_num_diff(function, arg: int, arg1: float, arg2: int, mode: str) -> tuple[Any, Any]:
    ...
    return an_integer, an_other_integer
```

Comment: @ЦветелинаВелкова, if one answer works you should mark it as working by accepting it.